# Ubuntu 22.04 Blank/Dim screen not working

Tags: 22.04, amd-graphics

Hardware: Amd Ryzen 3800x, Radeon 5700 (Desktop pc) (Two screens)

Software: ubuntu 22.04

It's now a couple of days that blank screen after a few minutes is not working anymore.
I checked if the settings where correct and that's ok.

I tried with no applications open and gnome-extensions disabled, still the same problem.

What can cause this? Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: Just I minute after startup, I get a crash of an application:
_usr_bin_ibus-daemon.128.crash